# Markov chain - a notation I don't understand

Tags: probability-theory, notation

I'm trying to understand the definition of a Markov chain. In the text they introduce the Markov chain by:

> "For random variables $X_{1}, \dots, X_{n}$ where $n\geq 3$, $X_{1} \rightarrow X_{2} \rightarrow \dots \rightarrow X_{n}$ forms a Markov chain if $ \\ p(x_{1}, x_{2}, \dots, x_{n} )p(x_{2})p(x_{3})\cdots p(x_{n-1}) = p(x_{1},x_{2})p(x_{2},x_{3})\cdots p(x_{n-1},x_{n})
> $"

What exactly does  $X_{1} \rightarrow X_{2} \rightarrow \dots \rightarrow X_{n}$ means? I think it means that the random variable $X_{1}$ has a non zero probability to turn into the random variable $X_{2}$ ect. (and they therefore call it "states").

But I'm not sure - Someone who can clarify this?

Comment: What is your text?

Comment: At least have a look a wikipedia before asking. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain

Comment: My text is called "a first course in information theory". I have checked wikipedia, but I didn't find any explanation/it stills confuse me. What does a "state" means?

Comment: My text does not explain the notation, but requires that the reader is familiar with probability theory. I have taken several probability courses, but have never seen this notation or use of term "state".  I got the book from a professor and asked him, but he is not familiar with markov chains. Therefore I need some references or a clarification. It is really annoying because I understand the other concepts introduced in the text/book.

Comment: Say, if you are talking about *A First Course in Information Theory* by Raymond W. Yeung, you might as well cite the very next line of the definition, no? Everything is in there.

Comment: I have added the next line. It is the book: How does this line explain what the notation means? What a "state" is and what the arrows indicate?

Comment: Right. One should not put too much into this notation. Each occurrence of $X_1\to X_2\to\ldots\to X_n$ in the book can be replaced by the more usual: $(X_k)_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n}$.

Comment: The set of states is the set $S$ such that $X_k:\Omega\to S$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each occurrence of $X_1→X_2→…→X_n$ can be replaced by the more usual $(X_k)_{1⩽k⩽n}$.