# I need a textbook! Information theory and probability

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, information-theory

I have posted some questions:

- [Probability result - 3 discrete random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/306447/probability-result-3-discrete-random-variables)
- [Markov chain - a notation I don't understand](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/306184/markov-chain-a-notation-i-dont-understand)
- [Random variables identities - how to make a formal proof.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/308338/random-variables-identities-how-to-make-a-formal-proof)

These questions reflect that I need to understand some concepts in probability theory. I would really like to hear if you, based on these questions, can help med find an appropriate textbook or a reference.

I have already learned the basic probability theory (have taken a course), but the book I have to read (A First Course in Information Theory by Raymond W. Yeung) requires that you are familiar with some concepts I am not used to.

Comment: I do not understand: you ask for a book in probability theory, an answer provides a book in information theory and you accept said answer?

Comment: I assumed that the book mentioned has a section describing the relevant probability theory in information theory.

Answer (score 2):

For Information Theory topic, I'm recommending a great book [Elements of Information Theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471062596) by M. Cover and A. Thomas. It covers wide range of topics of IT and includes a lot of examples and exercises.